# SP13: Lookup column with multiple selections

Tags: 2013, content-type, custom-list, lookup-column, multiple-values

In SP10 and later this was not possible, but it's hard for me to find if Microsoft has made it possible in SP13.  I have created a lookup column and wanted to be able to select multiple choices from the options. An easier solution would be to create a choice column and select checkboxes.  But I do not want others to go into the library settings to change the column choices. Think it's easier to update from a list for others that have minimal SP experience to update.

Does anyone know if adding a lookup column with multiple selections is possible in SP13? If so, how can I go about having this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can enable multi-select on a lookup field.

Under 'In this column:' where you pick the column in the list you want, there is a check box for Allow multiple values.